# What order to re-decorate bedroom

Tags: bedroom, renovation

I'm looking at completely re-decorating the main bedroom in my house - some of it I'd like to do myself and some I'm planning to get tradesmen in to help speed things up. That said, I've never really got much into DIY before so I'm not entirely sure what to expect and which order to do things in.

---

The list of jobs (with relevant tradie in brackets) that I can think of are as follows, in the order I think makes the most sense:

In any order...

- Replace main light and swap light switch for dimmer (electrician)
- Replace two radiators (plumber)
- Replace fitted wardrobe track and sliding doors (joiner)
- Replace internal storage of fitted wardrobe (joiner)
- Replace window sill (joiner)

...then when they're all done...

- Paint walls (decorator)

...lastly...

- Replace carpet (carpet fitter)
- Replace curtain rail (decorator)
- Build new bed, drawers, bedside table (handyman)

---

I'm thinking that with replacing the radiators, fitted wardrobe etc there may be some plastering or something needed before painting, but since it's my first rodeo I figured it's best to get the opinions of people who've done this kind of thing before :)

Is this roughly the right order, or am I overlooking one or more potential headaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested order:

1. Get electrician to look first, and make sure the junction boxes are good and don't need replacing or fixing.  If they do this should happen first.  Regardless, the lamp and switch replacement will be last.
2. So long as you'll be painting, *remove* the old radiators first. Remove the old window sills and do any other demolition.
3. Do all the carpentry
4. Do all the wall patching
5. Paint
6. Put in the new radiators, light and switch, and curtain rail.
7. Put in the carpet
8. Build furniture

If you have no experience, some of the things you can do that are good learning projects, depending on your appetite for buying tools, are:

- Build shelving in the cabinets
- Painting
- Assembling flat-pack furniture
- Cleaning up at each stage (don't underestimate the amount of work) and hauling garbage away.  Renovation produces more garbage than you expect.
- Replacing the switch (not the lamp, I don't recommend learning wiring with overhead work)
- Bleeding all the radiators after the plumber puts in the new ones

Overlooking:

- Look at the condition of all electrical outlets and replace any tired-looking ones, as they will stand out.
- Possibly making small floor repairs before new carpet ... levelling, removing squeaks, etc.

Comment: I would demo the wardrobe, then paint before installing the new wardrobe.  Actually, I'd remove the carpet before doing anything, but if the OP is farming all the work out, that may not be possible (although removing carpet ain't hard).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's super helpful. I'll get to Googling up some tips for the do-able things, and see if I can sort an electrician to check the junction boxes ASAP :)